# How To Get Values With preg_match Or any other Method

Tags: php

I am trying to make a function by with I want to get values of different URLs for example
here I have 2 URLs

> http://myurl.com/?a=c&q=ee&jpr=27abdc4365f7f99a3816eb815466c10d&device_id=b2ebd10b-6b63-4949-9c69-c96462df84b5

2nd URL is

> http://myurl.com/?a=c&q=ee&m11=78aswq82299938337h7733883392ra

it's only 2 I have more now I need the value of 32 character string any method I am applying preg_match but its not work for all only same thing is the value is in 32 character

Comment: `preg_match('/[a-z0-9]{32}/',$input,$match);` will match a continuous string of 32 letters/numbers. You can get fancier with `'/(?<==)[a-z0-9]{32}(?=&|$)/'`

Comment: bro please write is full i am writing is like this preg_match('#(?<==)[a-z0-9]{32}(?=&|$)#',$html,$match);
$track=$match[1];
echo $track;

Comment: If you always want to parse an URL, have a look at [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)

Comment: `parse_url()` in combination with `parse_str()` is all you need.

Comment: i m not much familiar with this fucntion kindly help me out to write this

Comment: You should check the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to split the URL into pieces (you need only the query string) then pass the query string to [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get the individual query variables and their values:

```
$url = 'http://myurl.com/?a=c&q=ee&jpr=27abdc4365f7f99a3816eb815466c10d&device_id=b2ebd10b-6b63-4949-9c69-c96462df84b5';
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

$vars = array();
parse_str($query, $vars);

print_r($vars);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [a] => c
    [q] => ee
    [jpr] => 27abdc4365f7f99a3816eb815466c10d
    [device_id] => b2ebd10b-6b63-4949-9c69-c96462df84b5
)
```

If the value you need is not always associated to the same key (the key is `jpr` in this example but it is `m11` in the other example) you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to 
keep only the entries that match your criteria (f.e. they values that have length `32` and are associated to keys having length `3`):

```
$filtered = array_filter(
    $vars,
    function($val, $key) { 
        return strlen($val) == 32 && strlen($key) == 3;
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);
print_r($filtered);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [jpr] => 27abdc4365f7f99a3816eb815466c10d
)
```

#### Remark

The third [parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#refsect1-function.array-filter-parameters) of [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is available only for PHP 5.6 and newer.

If you are stuck with an older version you cannot inspect the key in the filter callback function. If this is important for you, a simple [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop does the job even with less code:

```
$filtered = array();
foreach ($vars as $key => $val) {
    if (strlen($val) == 32 && strlen($key) == 3) {
        $filtered[$key] = $val;
    }
}
```